# Using hook in component

Tags: ember.js

I have a component where I'm using `didInsertElement` function. I need to make some changes in component based on its width and height. Now it works fine but I get many warnings about performance issues.

I read about new hooks (from 1.13): `didReceiveAttrs` for example. I tried to use it but got error on following ($() = null):

```
var recipeBoxHeight = this.$().find(".recipe-box").height();
var tagsHeight = this.$().find("#tags").height();
var recipeNameHeight = this.$().find(".recipe-name-text").height();
```

Is it possible to get these properties without warnings about performance problems?

Comment: Could you make them computed properties?

Comment: I need to change positions of some elements in a component according to its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap them in `Ember.run.schedule('afterRender',...)` so your code gets executed in `afterRender` queue of [run loop](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/run-loop/)

```
didInsertElement() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function() {
   var recipeBoxHeight = this.$().find(".recipe-box").height();
   var tagsHeight = this.$().find("#tags").height();
   var recipeNameHeight = this.$().find(".recipe-name-text").height();
  });
}
```

Comment: I did this and got rid of warnings. But it will it really improve performance, or it need just to deal with deprecation warnings?

Comment: it just makes your code run in right queue where manipulation with dom should happen, so it right thing to do and shouldn't degrade the performance not sure if it improves it

Comment: There's also the `didRender` hook, would that still throw the warning?

Comment: not sure about `didRender ` but it runs multiple times so might not be right place for initialization stuff